# Java Calendar Date still adding Time on UTC Date 00:00

Tags: java, java-calendar

I set my Calendar instance to a UTC date at 00:00 however once i return the result its 1 hour ahead

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TIMEZONE_UTC, Locale.ENGLISH);
cal.set(2017, 12 - 1, 15);
cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
// Fri Dec 15 01:00:00 CET 2017 but should be 00:00:00
```

I suppose there is the winter/summer offset but I didn't found any description in the Gregorian or Calendar Element to handle this issue

Comment: You are getting the correct time, 00:00:00 UTC. What is fooling you is that `Date.toString()` (implicitly called from `System.out.println()`) is converting the time to your own time zone (using the JVM time zone setting) for the string generated.

Comment: I recommend you stop using the long outdated `Calendar` class. [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), is so much nicer to work with. And using a `ZonedDateTime` (or `OffsetDateTime` or `Instant`) from the modern API will solve your issue.

Comment: Are you expecting midnight on this date in UTC to also be midnight (00:00:00) in the CET time zone simultaneously? Not possible, as **CET is an hour ahead of UTC on that date** for that particular unidentified zone. I say unidentified because  CET is not a time zone but the effect of a time zone such as `Europe/London`.

Comment: In fewer words: 00:00:00 UTC on that date ***is*** 01:00:00 CET.

Answer (score 4):

I am getting the impression that you are really after just the date of December 15, 2017, and just wanted to make sure that there is no unexpected hour-of-day? If so, `LocalDate` from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, is made for you:

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2017, Month.DECEMBER, 15);
System.out.println(ld);
```

This prints

```
2017-12-15
```

No hours, minutes or seconds to be concerned about.

If you *do* need a date-time at 00:00 UTC (the time I used to call midnight until [Basil Bourque’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921927/java-calendar-date-still-adding-time-on-utc-date-0000/47922101?noredirect=1#comment82814873_47923345)), there are several ways to obtain it. One of them is:

```
    OffsetDateTime utcDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2017, Month.DECEMBER, 15, 0, 0)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(utcDateTime);
```

This prints

```
2017-12-15T00:00Z
```

The `Z` in the end means UTC or offset zero. You see that the time of day is 00:00 as you wanted.

The `Calendar` class that you used in the question is long outdated, so I recommend you don’t use it anymore. `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API also known as JSR-310, is so much nicer to work with.

### What went wrong in your code?

While a `Calendar` does contain a time zone (you initialized it to `TIMEZONE_UTC`), a `Date` (another outdated class) doesn’t. So when you convert to `Date` using `cal.getTime()` you lose the information that you wanted the time to be in UTC. Next (and this confuses many), when you print the date, you implicitly call `Date.toString()`, and this method grabs your JVM’s time zone setting and produces a string  with the time in this time zone. So apparently you are (like I am) in a time zone that is at UTC+01:00 in December. The following two date-times denote *the same* point on the timeline:

```
Fri Dec 15 01:00:00 CET 2017
Fri Dec 15 00:00:00 UTC 2017
```

Comment: Good Answer, but I suggest using the phrase "first moment of the day" rather than "midnight". The "midnight" term is amorphous, meaning different things to different people in different contexts. Note that the Joda-Time project made a major breakthrough in dropping the concept(s) and the term, and deprecating several classes, instead going with a "start of day" concept in both the terminology and the classes.

Comment: Thx, @BasilBourque, edited.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you see local time printed is you're displaying it via an instance of Calendar using `Date.toString()` which uses the local timezone(implicitly use the system timezone).

Comment: This is incorrect, different semantics than the Question. The Question sets the `Calendar` object to 00:00:00 in UTC, then in calling `Calendar::getTime` instantiates a `Date` that carries no applicable time zone (always in UTC) but whose `Date::toString`  dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone which must one of the zones an hour ahead of UTC. In contrast, this Answer sets the `Calendar` object to 00:00:00 in BST (London time), **an entirely different moment**, an hour earlier than the moment in the Question.